# I want to get all the values of a select even if they are not selected. What should I do?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to get all the values of a select  in a Servlet even if the values are not selected. What should I do?

I know that I can fetch all the selected values using `request.getParameterValues("  ")`, but I want all the values as they are filled at the run time.

I have two Select and at runtime the user can insert options from one select to another one. Now on submit of the form I want to access all the values present in the second select.

The first Select is getting values from a database, not from any other servlet, and I want to access only a few of them which are inserted in second select by user

```
String nonconti = request.getParameter("non-conti");
if(nonconti.equals("yes")){
    String[] elLeaves = request.getParameterValues("addELDate");
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    for(int i=0; i<elLeaves.length;i++){
        try {
            if(!(elLeaves[i] == null || elLeaves[i].trim().equals("") || elDateList.contains(elLeaves[i]))){
                cal.setTime( formater1.parse(elLeaves[i]));
                if(!((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) || (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY))){
                    elDateList.add(formater1.format(formater1.parse(elLeaves[i])));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please update your question, add your form or explain what all terms, like addELDate

Comment: You've already populated the `<option>` elements of the previous response. Why don't you just rebuild them? `getParameter` will only give you what is selected.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to get the value which is not selected in the select element.
But yes there are some way around.

- You can store the value in session when you send it to display on the
  page and retrieve it upon submitting the form
- Just keep all the values of select in any hidden input as comma
  separted and get it on servlet and then split it and make array or in
  whatever form you want.

Comment: @Suresh I have two Select and at runtime user can insert options from one select to another one. now on submit of form I want to access all the values present in the second select.

Comment: The first Select is getting values from database not from any other servlet and I want to access only few of them which are inserted in second select by user

Comment: @JayKishan addElDate is the name of second select present in jsp.

Comment: I thing what you want to achieve is multi select but you have choosen a bad UI design for this.
This is not at all a good idea to have two select one for whole list and another for selected list.
If this is the case then you can try this plugin it might help in this scenario.
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Yes, I am trying to that only but I think I just remove the second select and just use only one.

Comment: yes use only one select with multiple attribute. If you want better ui view then you can use chosen plugin link i have given in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

form submit will send only selected Values to your servlet.

**UPDATE:** due to question update

also if user select an item from the first , you add this item to the second

your function thats adding selected Item to second, could add these selected items as hidden fields to your form like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="insertedItems[]" value="value of your new added options" />
```

in your servlet you get these options like:

```
String[] options = request.getParameterValues("insertedItems");
```

Comment: Actually Rami I dont want to access all of them but just few of them which got inserted in the second select.